# phonegap WFS proxy issue

Tags: android, cordova, openlayers

I encountered a problem when I try to package my sencha-touch app using phonegap. Everything works fine except accessing WFS in phonegap. (And the app has no problem running in browser, WFS access is OK)

My phonegap version is 2.9; openlayer version is 2.13

Here I present my simple code. You can also check the example codes in the following site: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wfs-filter.html

var rootUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + '/';
        var map;

```
    function init() {

        map = new OpenLayers.Map({
            div: "map",
            layers: [
            new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                "Natural Earth",
                "http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms",
                { layers: "topp:naturalearth" }
                ),
            new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("WFS", {
                strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
                protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                    url: rootUrl + 'proxy.py?url=http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs',
                    featureType: "tasmania_roads",
                    featureNS: "http://www.openplans.org/topp"
                }),
                styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                    strokeWidth: 3,
                    strokeColor: "#333333"
                }),
            })
            ],
            center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(146.7, -41.8),
            zoom: 6
        });

    }
```

In phonegap there's no problem accessing WMS, but when I try WFS, it never work.

Comparing to the link I showed you before, there's a road displayed in the map, and it is obtained through WFS. In my phonegap app, the road will not be displayed.

I'm wondering whether it is a WFS issue, or phonegap issue. Something is blocking my access to WFS in my phonegap app.

Please give me some suggestions and hints, guys! I will really appreciate it.

```
function getLayerList() {
        $.ajax({ url: rootUrl + 'proxy.py?url=http://192.168.0.23/LBEService/Service1.svc/GetEventList',
            //async: false,
            data: JSON.stringify({}),
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                $("#demo").html(result[0].event_NAME);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        }).done(function () {

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the domain that is hosting the WFS to the white list?

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In my config.xml file under xml folder, I can find this "<access origin="*"/>", which should mean that all domains are accessible, but phonegap still ignore my access to WFS. Could you please give more hints, I really appreciate it.

Comment: And also, when I disable the access to all domains in phonegap, the WMS then become inaccessible, which means  "<access origin="*"/>" is really working.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the requests through safari remove inspector or fiddler or something? To see if they are actually getting out of phonegap and what they look like.

Comment: I tried fiddler and wireshark, the result is WMS detected, but nothing about WFS. So I'm wondering whether it is a bug of phonegap?

Comment: How does open layers make the request? XHR?

Comment: And I also tried some codes that you can read above, getLayerList function, in which we call the web service, it is XHR, and it worked in phonegap. So still only when we try to call WFS, there's a problem.

Comment: Strange. Not sure what else to try at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

On android PhoneGap window.location.protocol is 'file:' and window.location.hostname is "", so your app will probably be looking for file://proxy.py? which doesn't exist on your device.

To solve this issue I test the protocol, and set up OpenLayers.Proxy accordingly, thus:

```
if( location.protocol == 'file:' ) {
    OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "";
} else {
    OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=";
}
```

So in your case, if protocol is 'file:', I think you need to drop 'proxy.py?'

Tip: debug your android app using Chrome on your PC (chrome://inspect/#devices) and you'll see the request that android is making.